# What are the various branches in a github "project page" cloned repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub repository that I've cloned to my local.

When I run `git show-ref` on my locally cloned repo I get following output:

```
8d88cfa72092d62ccc197192b62d3befe1ecd9c8 refs/heads/HEAD
0048436ad5e3db15cb92070f03704a0637a60359 refs/heads/gh-pages
8d88cfa72092d62ccc197192b62d3befe1ecd9c8 refs/heads/master
8d88cfa72092d62ccc197192b62d3befe1ecd9c8 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
0048436ad5e3db15cb92070f03704a0637a60359 refs/remotes/origin/gh-pages
8d88cfa72092d62ccc197192b62d3befe1ecd9c8 refs/remotes/origin/master
```

- What is the difference between `refs/heads/HEAD` and
  `refs/heads/master`? The github web interface shows only `master`.
- What is the difference between `refs/heads` and `refs/remotes`.

Comment: Why is the title "Branching on github"? You don't ask about branching in the question body.

Comment: @sashoalm I'm trying to understand various branches in a github repo. Please feel free to edit it with a more appropriate title.

Comment: You should edit it yourself and put a good title. It's your question, it's your job to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: @sashoalm because a gh-pages name is something that makes ony sense on GitHub for a "Project page" (https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/)

Comment: @VonC I don't see how that explains the title though. It seems to be quite different from the question.

Comment: @eis Ok. I have updated the title accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between refs/heads/HEAD and refs/heads/master?

It is like a symbolic link (a symref) in order to reference the branch by default (the one you see when you clone)
See "[Git References](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References#The-HEAD)"

> The HEAD file is a symbolic reference to the branch you’re currently on.
>   By symbolic reference, we mean that unlike a normal reference, it doesn’t generally contain a SHA-1 value but rather a pointer to another reference.
>   If you look at the file, you’ll normally see something like this:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

> What is the difference between refs/heads and refs/remotes

Those are your local and remote references for each branch: you can have done new commits on local which are not yet present on the GitHub repo. (or vice-versa)

See "[Git Branching - Remote Branches](http://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)":

[image: http://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0322-tn.png]

Note: In a [GitHub project page](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/), the `gh-pages` is typically an orphan branch (you never merge it to any other branches).