# how to automatically update working tree when updating-ref of a checked out branch

Tags: git

I have `mk` branch checked out. Now I do `git fetch origin` to fetch `origin/mk` branch. This branch was rebased and I have no local changes on it so I simply want to move local `mk` branch pointer to the fetched remote one, so I do the following:

```
$ git update-ref -m "Updating mk to remote ..." refs/heads/mk refs/remotes/origin/mk
```

The operation seems to successful as proved by `show-ref`:

```
$ git show-ref mk
a885dad11c37e5c03cc4937766d62e181984c1aa refs/heads/mk
a885dad11c37e5c03cc4937766d62e181984c1aa refs/remotes/origin/mk
```

However, the commit `a885dad` wasn't checked out to working directory. Why? Can it be checkout automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, as mentioned in "[Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722977/6309)", a simple `git fetch -u origin mk:mk` would have done the same (for fast-foward merge).

The question is: are those commands updating HEAD or not?

In the case of the [`git update-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref), a separate `git update-ref -m "Updating mk to remote ..." HEAD refs/heads/mk` would be needed.

But using the `-u` in [`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) should allow to update HEAD as well:

```
-u
--update-head-ok
```

> By default `git fetch` refuses to update the head which corresponds to the current branch. This flag disables the check.
>   This is purely for the internal use for [`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) to communicate with `git fetch`, and unless you are implementing your own Porcelain you are not supposed to use it.

Note that those commands would not update the working tree.
You would still need a separate `git checkout -- .`.

Comment: thanks! I don't quite understand why I would need to update `HEAD` in my case: since `mk` is checked out `HEAD` points to it already. I also tried to lookup this particular structure `git checkout -- .` and couldn't find - can you please point me where I can read about it (I assume it is similar to `reset --hard HEAD`)?

Comment: I will,  when I'll get back home in 2 hours

Comment: @Maximus it is similar indeed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3639387/6309 I use git checkout usually because I have content filter driver (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27665008/6309, like https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/b7c1d6c48d76859605f4a06896e0e1f797656c82/gitolite/config#L13-L15), and they are triggered by checkout (https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/b7c1d6c48d76859605f4a06896e0e1f797656c82/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh#L21). Inb your case,  a `git reset --hard` is enough.

Comment: got you, thanks a lot! Can you also comment please on this one _I don't quite understand why I would need to update HEAD in my case: since mk is checked out HEAD points to it already_? I assume that maybe you wasn't talking about my case in particular, but about `update-ref` in general in that it doesn't update HEAD, correct?

Comment: @Maximus yes, correct. In your case, HEAD is already a symref to your branch (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28557592/6309)

Comment: fantastic, thanks a lot! Everything's clear now. Best!